# Number missing in section hierarchy

Tags: sectioning, thesis

I have a .tex file where I am taking two `.tex` files (for example, `a.tex` and `b.tex`) as input. If I change their order then everything is fine. But, with the current order there is a problem in section numbering (for example, Section 5.1.1 is coming as 5..1, I mean in the second layer in the hierarchy number is missing ). I want to print the two `.tex` files in the current order. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: You are a member of TeX.SE for 6 years by now and yet do not post a compilable example with the two extra files `a.tex` and `b.tex`??? This is subject to guessing and I suspect some redefinition of `\thesubsection`, either directly or via a 'wrapper' such as `\counterwithin*`. Also, in as much is this related to very vague [tag:thesis]?

Comment: you have something like `\renewcommand\thesection{..}` in your first external file

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sorry, added one now.

Comment: @RIchardWilliams: Yes, but `a.tex` and `b.tex` are still not there. Where do we get the strange class file? Also `etex` isn't necessary any longer. And your `\newcommand`s will produce spurious spaces

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: problem solved. I had an appendix at the end of a.tex. That was creating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something line the one below. I also find useful when you have a big thesis, to separate all your sections in different files. You can leave your main.tex file in the root folder and inside there create another one and call it 'main' where inside this one you can have all your chapters. You could even create different folders for each chapter, but then you need to change the path in the "include".

So:

**main.tex file could have:**

> `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
>   %%%%% MAIN: The chapters of the thesis
>   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
>   \include{main/Part0}
>   \include{main/ch1_Introduction}
>   %Part I: Earth and Beyond
>   \include{main/PartI}
>   \include{main/ch2_EarthAndBeyond}`

**Part0.tex file could have:**

> `\part{Introduction}{}`

**ch1_Introduction.tex file could have:**

> `\chapter{Introduction}
>   \section*{Earth - Intro}
>   \section*{Moon - Intro}
>   \section*{Mars - Intro}`

**PartI.tex file could have:**

> `\part{Earth}{}
>   \label{PartI}`

**ch2_EarthAndBeyond.tex file could have:**

> `\chapter{Discussing about Earth}
>   \section{Introduction}
>   \subsection{Europe}
>   \subsection{Asia}`

Comment: At the moment I don't see how this answers the question.